# What is considered a normal car?

Tags: terminology, gran-turismo-6

Some races are for "normal" cars only. What makes a car "normal"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any car considered "normal" is street legal when you buy it from the dealership.

So any car that is not a concept car, not a tuner car and not a racing car.

Answer (score 0):

Normal road car means a production car, it's practically everything in the game that isn't a concept/VGT or a modified car.